# Can't find the cause of user credential prompts in SharePoint site

Tags: authentication, reporting-services

I have a SharePoint 2013 instance that runs our company intranet site. This past weekend we moved our site to a new set of servers and we also set the site up use SSL (https). Since this move, some, but not the majority users are being asked for user credentials when the site comes up. We have spent 2 days trying to figure this out and this is what we have determined:

Users can hit cancel or the x to close the credentials window, and the site loads fine.
This only happens for about 30% of all the users.
I am one of those users and I am Site Collection Admin and Farm Admin.
Once the user dismisses the credentials window, the user isn't prompted again during his/her current session.
I have found that if I sit on a certain page on the site and return the home page (say after 15 minutes or so), that I will get prompted again.
It appears as if this issue only relates to the home page.
We have applied the recommended fixes for the Loopback check issue as describe here
The home page does have a Page Viewer control that has a URL path that points to a SQL Server Report server. Both are part of the same domain. (Intranet site url is https://intranet.mycompany.com and the report server is https://[servername].mycompany.com)
We're looking for any information that could help us figure out why this is happening or where to look, as we have exhausted most options.

Comment: One possibility is that a certain file being requested by the homepage is still being requested through http... that might trigger the credential prompt.

If you run the Network trace in Chrome or IE, do any files come up with a 401 error after declining the prompt?

Comment: No.  I think it is related to our Citrix NetScaler and caching. We turned of the caching on the NetScaler and our issue went away.

Comment: Any more information on this? I also suddenly have most users getting prompted for credentials. But the page seems to load in its entirety.

Comment: Sorry no, I don't know much about the netscaler and the caching that was causing the issue.